# Make a Y*Z in a matrix and not a line (in Python 2.7.14)

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to python programming and for school I have to make a simulation of the multiplication table from 1 to 10. This needs to be in a matrix.

The code I wrote is:

```
for y in range(1, 11):
  for z in range(1, 11):
    print y*z
```

However, when i try to run this, it all comes in one line down and not a matrix... I have looked for an awnser and in python 3.0 or higher they have the "end=" command but I cannot use this so I was wondering how to fix this in 2.7.14.

Comment: Seeing as this is for a school homework, I'm not going to give you a complete answer to your question. But I would suggest you look into lists, then you can make each row of your matrix a list, and then print each list in turn. Here might be a good place to start: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: by matrix do you mean a display with two dimensions or a data structure shaped like a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can create matrix use python list comprehension like this

```
multiplication_table = [
    [y*z for z in range(1, 11)] for y in range(1, 11)
]
```